# Extjs Paging Toolbar in Grid does not work

Tags: c#, asp.net, extjs, paging, toolbar

I have searched high and low for this problem... and I found a lot of people have the same problem but none have a definite solution...
Basically I have a grid on extjs... it gets data from sqldb. It loads fine using json. "But"... when trying to implement paging, this is where it gets messy...

1. pagesize is set to 5... which means first page should only show 5 records, but my grid shows the entire records
2. Even though the "next" button exists, it does not work technically because the entire record is already there on the first page
3. I set page.loadPage(2)... and the message says "Displaying Second Page", but it's actually displaying the entire records
4. The page number in "Page _ of 6" is always blank. see below image...

   [image]

Below is my store...

```
       var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        storeId: 'myData',
        pageSize: 5,
        autoLoad: true,
        method: "POST",
        remoteSort: true,
        fields: [
    { name: 'Q1', type: 'int' },
    { name: 'Q2', type: 'int' },
    { name: 'Q3', type: 'int' },
    { name: 'Q4', type: 'int' },
    { name: 'Q5', type: 'int' },
    { name: 'Improvements', type: 'string' },
    { name: 'Comments', type: 'string' }
    ],

        sorters: [
        {
            property: 'Q1',
            direct: 'ASC'
        }
     ],

        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: 'GridView/writeRecord',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                totalProperty: "count",
                root: "myTable"
            }
        },
        autoLoad: { params: { start: 0, limit: 5} }   

    });

    this.grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
        title: ' ',
        trackMouseOver: true,
        disableSelection: true,
        autoHeight: true,
        store: store,
        loadMask: true,
        height: 500,
        width: 800,
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        columns: [

        { header: 'Q1',
            sortable: true, dataIndex: 'Q1'
        },
        { header: 'Q2',
            sortable: true, dataIndex: 'Q2'
        },
        { header: 'Q3',
            sortable: true, dataIndex: 'Q3'
        },
        { header: 'Q4',
            sortable: true, dataIndex: 'Q4'
        },
        { header: 'Improvements', flex: 1,
            sortable: true, dataIndex: 'Improvements'
        },
        { header: 'Comments', flex: 1,
            sortable: true, dataIndex: 'Comments'
        }
    ],
        bbar: Ext.create('Ext.PagingToolbar', {
            store: store,
            displayInfo: true,
            preprendButtons: true,
            displayMsg: 'Displaying Surveys {0} - {1} of {2}',
            emptyMsg: "No Surveys to display"

        })
    });
```

and this is my JSON... it has actually 30 records but I trimmed it down...

```
  {
  "count": 30,
  "myTable": [
  {
  "Q1": "1",
  "Q2": "1",
  "Q3": "1",
  "Q4": "1",
  "Improvements": "",
  "Comments": "1"
},
{
  "Q1": "3",
  "Q2": "2",
  "Q3": "2",
  "Q4": "2",
  "Improvements": "This is A very long comment. What do you think?",
  "Comments": "Agreed"
},
{
  "Q1": "4",
  "Q2": "2",
  "Q3": "4",
  "Q4": "3",
  "Improvements": "Hello2",
  "Comments": "Hello2"
},
{
  "Q1": "3",
  "Q2": "2",
  "Q3": "2",
  "Q4": "1",
  "Improvements": "Hello4",
  "Comments": "Hello4"
}
```

]
}

Also if it helps this is how I get my Json

```
        string sqlquery = "SELECT Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4, Improvements, Comments FROM ITable";
        conn.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter cmd = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlquery, conn);
        SqlCommand comd = new SqlCommand(sqlquery, conn);
        DataSet myData = new DataSet();
        cmd.Fill(myData, "myTable");

        comd.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ITable";
        Int32 count = (Int32)comd.ExecuteScalar();

        comd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();


        var results = (new

        {

            TotalNumber = count,

            myTable = myData

        });

        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { count=count, myTable = myData.Tables[0] }, Formatting.Indented,
                        new JsonSerializerSettings
                        {
                            ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
                        });
```

I know my Json is right... and it reads 30 records because is says "Displaying _ of 30"... I just have no clue what I am doing wrong... It cannot be a browser issue... why is it throwing up all in one page? anybody?

Comment: you have autoLoad property defined twice and you did not show how you configured your grid and paging tool bar.

Comment: hi dbrin... eventhough I take one of em off... I still don't get it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using the paging toolbar, the server is supposed to page the data for you. You don't feed it all of the records at once.

The paging toolbar will send requests asking for each page, and the server is supposed to return just the records for that page.

If you want to page with in memory data (fetching them all at once, you have to implement your own, or use one of the extensions.

See the section titled "Paging with Local Data" at http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.toolbar.Paging

Therefore, to use it as intended, you have to change your server code to account for the `start` and `limit` HTTP parameters

Comment: Wow... no wonder... thanks so much Juan... I knew I was missing something... lemme take a look at that page and will update you

Comment: Hi Juan... I went over the page and tried everything on it... I would actually like to prefer the first option... i.e I don't want paging with Local data... Do you have any example that shows how the server pages data according to toolbar's request... thanks so much

Comment: @EagleFox That is a separate question, here at Stack Overflow we prefer that you ask one question per post, that way it will be most useful to other users. You should mark this as the accepted answer ask a new question and link to the new question from here. Your answer depends on the SQL server that you're using, in mysql it's as easy as `limit(most, start)`